# What is the proper word to designate this small bag?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I have this tiny (5x4x1cm) bag that closes with a zip, which I use to store earplugs:

[image]

What is the proper word to designate this small bag?

---

What I thought of:

- "sac" and "sacoche" sound too big for this.

Comment: Oops, I answered in French...

Comment: @XouDo pas de souci, merci pour ta réponse !

Comment: That would be a baguette.

Comment: @drone6502 I see what you did there...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Voici les mots qui me viennent à l'esprit pour cet objet :

- (petite) **trousse**

https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/trousse

> trousse : Poche, étui à compartiments pour ranger un ensemble d'objets. *Trousse de médecin*. *Trousse de toilette*

Dans l'usage quotidien, le mot fait généralement référence à un étui souple en cuir ou tissu muni d'une fermeture éclair (trousse d'écolier contenant les crayons ou bien trousse de toilette pour les brosses à dents etc.).

- **Pochette** (on préciserait peut-être : zippée en tissu).

mais le terme est moins précis comme en témoigne [le robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/pochette) :

> 1. Petite enveloppe (d'étoffe, de papier…). Pochette d'allumettes. Pochette-surprise (...)
> 2. Petite pièce d'étoffe disposée dans la poche de poitrine pour l'orner.
> 3. Petit sac à main sans poignée.

Comment: pochette ou petite trousse. :)

Comment: I would use `pochette` more than `trousse` personnaly but both of them are correct

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by [@MatthieuM.'s comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49492/what-is-the-proper-word-to-designate-this-small-bag/49494?noredirect=1#comment101372_49494) I'm reordering the paragraphs in this answer.

I've been looking at commercial sites that sell this kind of objects specifically made to store your earplugs, they call them  *étui pour écouteurs*, *pochette pour écouteurs* or *sac de protection pour écouteurs*,  ***étui*** seems to be the most common though.

But that's not the word I use. The small bag I use to store my earplugs I just call it *petit sac*. *Sac* can be  any size, *sacoche* is usually reserved for bigger sized objects. If you want just a single word then there are two that come to mind :

- *poche* (contenant servant au transport d’objets ou de liquides, [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poche#Nom_commun_1)).
- *bourse* which is an exact synonym of *porte-monnaie* but the name is independent of its use.

The object on the picture looks exactly like the purse I use to put my change in, so if you hadn't said what you use if for I'd have called it *porte-monnaie*.  Of course nothing prevents you to use the word independently of what you use it for.

Comment: I could have called it porte-monnaie too (even though I don't use such a thing for my coins).

Comment: I would suggest to make étui more prominent in this answer, since you mention it's the most common on commercial sites; specifically, put it ahead of your own potential ideas, as usage > ideas.

Comment: @XouDo *Portemonnaie* seems to be a word other languages have [borrowed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/porte-monnaie#French). If you look at the [portemonnaie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte-monnaie) article on wikipedia in different languages they have different pictures, and for French it is the same shape, and zipped like the one shown by the OP. I wonder if this is what is called* porte-monnaie dit « français » in Québec. ([We were discussing it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60118656#60118656)). About 60-70 years ago this kind of porte-monnaie was very common.

Answer (score 1):

[*Pochon*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pochon/61912) could fit:

> **Sac** de papier, de plastique, **de tissu** dans lequel on emballe des
> denrées, **des produits commerciaux**.

Comment: Note that the younger generation might expect a *pochon* to contain some green illicit substance, not earplugs.

Comment: @NoëlloMiqueron Oui, la description ("petit sac de plastique dans lequel on emballe des denrées") semble correspondre.

Comment: @EricDuminil the younger generation and customs agents + police. My pochon got searched more than once...

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You've just lost me hahaha, you mean a bag like a standard plastic bag for groceries or the object in your image? I'm French speaking, but weed is legal in my jurisdiction and I don't use the word _pochon_ nor really fully know what it typically is, as I neither do (weird sentence) _pochette, poche_ and all since _pochette_ (d'un disque) refers for me (Qc.) to a vinyl album packaging or the lyrics inside a cd disc ahahha and the latter is simply a pocket re pants. Funny stuff, I'm just clueless here.

Comment: @NoëlloMiqueron the object in my image :) with Eric's comment, I now have the connotation pochon -> drug.